# Change mouse pointer on click and get back on release

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a project where I am using google hand cursors:

https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur
and
https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur

I have few siders and I want to make
***openhand*** cursor to be default on mouse over (.slide:hover),
and when is clicked on *.slide* to change cursor to ***closedhand***.

I found a few answers on the Internet, but nowhere I have been able to find an answer how to get back cursor when click is released.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `.slide:hover` as you suggested for the open hand. Then for the closed hand on click `.slide:active`.

See this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enk8o1sr/).

```
.slide:hover {
    cursor: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur'), auto;
}

.slide:active {
    cursor: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur'), auto;
}
```